# wide sense stationary process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $y_n$ be a wide sense stationary process (*wss*), i.e., where the mean is independent of $n$ and the correlation depends solely upon $|n_1 - n_2|$.

Let us define:

> $u_n = a_1 y_{n−1} + \ldots + a_p y_{n-p}$

with $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k = 1, \ldots p$.

Is $u_n$ also a wide sense stationary process?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u_n$ is also a wide stationary process. Let $\mu=\mathsf{E}[y_n]$ and $B(k)=\mathsf{cov}(y_{n+k},y_n)$. Then
\begin{gather}
\mathsf{E}[u_n]=\mathsf{E}\Bigl[\sum_{i=1}^pa_iy_{n-i}\Bigr]=\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^pa_i\Bigr)\mu\quad\text {(it doesn't depend $n$)},\\
\mathsf{cov}(u_{n+k},u_n)=\mathsf{cov}\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^pa_iy_{n+k-i},\sum_{j=1}^pa_j{y_{n-j}}\Bigr)=\sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{j=1}^pa_ia_jB(k-i+j)\\
\text {(it doesn't depend $n$ also)}.
\end{gather}
Therefore, $u_n$ is a wide stationary process.